# How to extract translation keys from the parameter of 't' function in react-i18next to the separate type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

How can I extract the type of the possible keys from `t` function? It works perfectly when I use it inside components after `useTranslation()` call, so I want to use the type anywhere, for example, as the type of a prop.

### To Reproduce

I tried something like this, but it looks weird and I get the error `TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`

```
 type TranslationKeys = Parameters<ReturnType<typeof useTranslation>['t']>[0]
```

My declaration file:

```
import en from 'assets/i18n/en-US.json';

type Resources = typeof en;

declare module 'react-i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    resources: Resources;
  }
}
```

en-US.json file:

```json
{
  "posts": {
    "headerTitle": "Posts",
    "id": "Id",
    "deviceId": "Device Id",
    ...
  },
  "users": {
    "headerTitle": "Users",
     ....
  },
}
```

I want to have a type of these values: `'posts:headerTitle' | 'post:id' | 'post:deviceId' | 'users:headerTitle'` and so on. And useTranslation function can infer the possible keys internally to use them in `t` function call, I want to use them too

I can construct it on myself by `Resources` manipulations, but it should be possible to do it "natively"

### Your Environment

- *i18next version*: 21.8.1
- *react-i18next*: 11.16.9
- *typescript*: 4.6.4

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq1orm) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: what should the resulting type look like?

Comment: Why not look at what the library uses, and reuse the same?

Comment: I don't know  how to get it from here https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/2759ed22edbe6d52335d5b06657a51b0c1e9f336/ts4.1/index.d.ts#L239

Answer (score 1):

I have only tested with i18next 22.x.x version:

```
import { Namespace, TFuncKey } from 'i18next';
TFuncKey<Namespace>
```